# DokuWiki: Mix content from human with content from automated process

Tags: automation, content-management-system, dokuwiki

We run DokuWiki.

We have one page for every server.

We want to mix automated content (like number of CPUs) with content created by human beings by hand and keyboard.

What is an easy and not so "dirty" way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

- [Include](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:include) generated pages and their sections into user-maintained pages or vice versa. As a benefit you will be able to forbid user access to generated pages(namespaces) via [ACL](https://www.dokuwiki.org/acl).
- Use plugins like [data](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:data) or [sqlite](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:sqlite) to include smaller pieces of information on the page.
- It might be enough to have [discussions](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:discussion) available for generated pages.